# Using local methods for querying data from DocumentDB

Tags: linq, iqueryable, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following function in my base repository

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink)
            .Where(doc => doc.Type == DocType)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(doc => 
                   doc.Owner == user.Id()
                || user.InGroup(doc.Owner)
                || doc.Public);
    }
```

I have two extension methods on the ClaimsPrincipal class. `Id()` just returns `.FindFirst("user_id").Value` and `.InGroup(<id>)` checks if the user has a group-membership to the group that owns the document.

However, am I correct in assuming that once I call `.AsEnumerable()` the query goes to the database with only the first where-clause, returns everything it matches, and then does the second where-clause on the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, am I correct in assuming that once I call .AsEnumerable() the query goes to the database

Not quite.

When this method returns, it won't have hit the database *at all*. `AsEnumerable()` doesn't force the query to execute - it's basically *just* a cast to `IEnumerable<T>`.

You're right in saying the first `Where` is performed at the database and the second `Where` is performed client-side, but "returns everything it matches" suggests that's done in bulk - which it might be, but it may be streamed as well. The client-side `Where` will certainly stream, but whether the `IQueryable<T>` implementation fetches everything eagerly is an implementation detail.

If you're really only interested in which filters are in the database and which are local though, you're correct.

Comment: But the bottom line is that I could be moving every document of type ``DocType`` from DocumentDB to the server before doing the last of the filtering?

Comment: @Christian: Yes. If your db can filter on Owner and Public, I suggest you call user.Id and save the result in a local variable, then move those bits of the query up.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it otherwise. Instead of ``InGroup()`` I created a method that just returns an array of group-id's and use ``.Contains()`` on that instead. Now it's supported by IQueryable.